# Heckman selection model for unbalanced panel data

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, heckman, heterogeneity

I want to apply a heckman sample selection model (implemented for example in the R package `sampleSelection`, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/sampleSelection.pdf)). However I have an unbalanced panel with multiple time periods $t=1,..,T$ and varying individuals $i_t=1,...,n_t$ in each period. Most individuals are observed for all $T$ periods but there are however some dropouts und newcomers over time.

Technically the individuals select themselves in each period into an exchange with each other  (selection equation) and exchange then in the second stage a continuous quanitity (mean equation). Because I am concerned with individual- and time-based heterogeneity I want to control for potential unobserved  time- and individual-related effects.

I guess that including a (non-)linear time-trend as well as time-fixed effects (i.e. a dummy variable $\delta_t$ for each year) in the selection and mean equation are standard and accepted practice. But what about individual-specific effects? Since I am modelling exchange I want to control for an individual-specific sender ($s_{i_{t}}$) and a receiver effect ($r_{j_{t}}$). So in both equations I want to include $\delta_t,s_{i_t}$ and $r_{j_t}$.

It is, however, highly controversial to include fixed effects in the probit equation because of the incidental parameter problem (see [here](http://www.econ.brown.edu/Faculty/Tony_Lancaster/papers/IncidentalParameters1948.pdf) and [here](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-03/msg00364.html)), i.e. the estimators will not be consistent and on top of that I run potentially into computational trouble. Otherwise I could use no fixed effects in the probit but in the mean equation, but this is inconsistent with the heckman model. At least I thought about using random effects in the selection and the mean equation. Do you have some solutions for me?

Comment: See Kyriazidou 1997 (Econometrica, Vol.65, No.6). I got the same problem, but found no ready implementation.

Comment: I will have a look at the reference. At least from the abstract it sounds very interesting.

Comment: There is a new Stata package that provides a methods that may help you: https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458770.html